What causes pending transactions?
I have a live app integrated with PayPal api. One of my customers made a transaction with a merchant on my platform, but the status of the payment capture is PENDING with the status_details reason being PENDING_REVIEW. What could be causing the transaction to be pending review? Is there anything I or the merchant can do to resolve this transaction or will it automatically be resolved? Was also wondering if there's a PayPal api I can use to monitor the status of the transaction? Any help is appreciated!

Review status is a business issue, account owner should contact PayPal to inquire about it.
For post-payment programmatic notification of transaction status changes you can use webhooks or the old IPN service.
